# How to get list of points inside shape which is difference between 2 polygons in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have these 2 polygons which stored in numpy arrays:

```
[[222 322] [250 313] [278 308] [294 312] [311 309] [331 317] [350 329] [331 352]
 [311 360] [293 361] [274 358]]

[[233 324] [276 326] [294 328] [311 327] [340 331] [311 334] [294 334]]
```

i need the get all the points between these 2 polygon

Comment: What did you try? Please include your broken code.

Comment: i have 2 polygons (one inside another) and i'm trying to get the area between them

Comment: So you basically want Area of Polygon 1 - Area of Polygon 2?

Comment: exactly what i need

Comment: Ok no problem, give me one second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: `pip install shapely`

Second:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
poly1 = Polygon([(222, 322), (250, 313), (278, 308), (294, 312), (311, 309), (331, 317), (350, 329), (331, 352), (311, 360), (293, 361), (274, 358)])

poly1.area
>>> 4369.5

poly2 = poly2 = Polygon([(233, 324), (276, 326), (294, 328), (311, 327), (340,331), (311, 334), (294, 334)])

poly2.area
>>> 420.0

area_diff = poly1.area - poly2.area
area_diff

>>> 3949.5
```

Is this what you need?

Edit:

Seems you also want the bounds of the leftover area. Not a problem. Here is how we would arrive at that.

```
points = poly1.difference(poly2)
points.bounds
>>> (222.0, 308.0, 350.0, 361.0)
```

Edit 2:

I realize now you may need all points of the leftover area, and that can be accomplished as such.

```
list(points.exterior.coords)
>>> [(222.0, 322.0),
 (274.0, 358.0),
 (293.0, 361.0),
 (311.0, 360.0),
 (331.0, 352.0),
 (350.0, 329.0),
 (331.0, 317.0),
 (311.0, 309.0),
 (294.0, 312.0),
 (278.0, 308.0),
 (250.0, 313.0),
 (222.0, 322.0)]
```

Comment: First thank you for your reply
second i need to get the points of the area_diff so i can color it
and if that possible is there anyway i can convert the numpy array to shaply polygon?

Comment: You want the boundaries of the leftover area?

Comment: yes i'm using opencv to draw the first polygon,the second one and i want o draw the leftover area

Comment: thank you .. this is what i need